# Не обновляет дату

Tags: mysql, sql

Почему не обновляет дату?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecbc1/3

```
UPDATE user SET DATE_ADD(access, 2 MONTH)  WHERE id = 1
```

---

```
- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Янв 01 2018 г., 14:35
-- Версия сервера: 5.6.24
-- Версия PHP: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `lesson26`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `paid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `access` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `paid`, `access`) VALUES
(1, 'Дима', 1, '2018-03-01 13:12:41');

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_ADD` не изменяет значение поля, а возвращает новую дату

```
UPDATE user SET access = DATE_ADD(access, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)  WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: не работает это

Comment: @DivMan Можем устроить дискуссию: Вы будете говорить - "не работает", а я буду говорить - "работает". С Новым Годом!